# Npm install programmatically doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to use the npm api programmatically, as shown below:

```
var npm = require("npm");

npm.load(npm.config, function (err) {
    npm.commands.install(["express"], function(err, done) {
        console.log(err, done);
    });
});
```

It returns the following error:

```
C:\...>node app.js

C:\...\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:323
    value = -1 !== value.indexOf("\n")
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
    at C:\...\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:323:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at makeEnv (C:\...\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.j
s:313:8)
    at C:\...\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:49:15
    at C:\...\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:122:12
    at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:107:15)
```

I am using the following versions:
node - v0.10.33
npm - 1.4.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass npm it's own config file. The load function should take it's own config, or an empty object if you aren't configuring anything. Try this:

```
var npm = require("npm");

npm.load({}, function (err) {
    npm.commands.install(["express"], function(err, done) {
        console.log(err, done);
    });
});
```